# Show the delta of D5:D4 only when D5 has a value

Tags: excel, google-sheets

can't wrap my head around the syntax needed:
Subtracting the values in (D5: D4) only when D5 is not blank

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: =IF(D5,D5-D4,) should work

Comment: What do you mean by delta? Try- `=IF(D5>0,D5-D4,""` this will work both in excel and gs.

Comment: THANK YOU! =IF(D5,D5-D4,) is what I was shooting for.

Answer (score 0):

Excel:
You may want to use ISBLANK(D5) in the IF condition.
Or ISNUMBER() might be more suitable for your use case.